# python set of all subsets m indices from a set of size n

Tags: python, algorithm, memory, set, combinations

I need to find the set of all subsets of size m for a given set of size n. Therefore in the simplest version of my algorithm I use **itertools.combinations()** but since n = 566 and m = 11 I can't manage to get to the end of computation even if I wait 10 hours then the process return **killed: 9**. Moreover I would need to have a set of sets as objects (where the elements of the set are sets as well) and not a list of tuples instead so that make the issue even more complicated computationally speaking.

```
from itertools import combinations, product  
S = set()
Sf = frozenset(combinations(xrange(1, 566), 11))
for i in Sf:
    t = frozenset(i)
    S.add(t)
```

The more sofisticated version is instead to use **intertools.combinations()** on two sets A and B with n = 566 both and m = 2 and 9 respectively (I will call them d and k) and then final set S is made up by the union of the elements of this two sets (a and b for elements of A and B) in the way that S = {t = a ∪ b: a in A, b in B, a ∩ b = 0}

```
A = set()
As = frozenset(combinations(xrange(1, 566), 2))
for i in As:
    a = frozenset(i)
    A.add(a)

B = set()
Bs = frozenset(combinations(xrange(1, 566), 9))
for j in Bs:
    b = frozenset(j)
    B.add(b)

ab = set()
ba = set()
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        if i.issubset(j):
            ab.add(i)
            ba.add(j)

A_ab = A.difference(ab)
B_ba = B.difference(ba)

S = frozenset(product(B_ba, A_ab))
```

In the end I think my problems are computational time and memory usage (I'm using python 2.7.9 on i7  1.7 GHz with 8 GB of RAM mac). Obviously if there were a more efficient and optimized algorithm it would welcome!

Comment: I assume that you're not planning to look at all 4.3e22 combinations yourself, so perhaps you could tell us what you're planning to do with them.

Comment: I'm performing a multiple output multivariate quantile regression on a time series of 566 events then I need this set to pass from the univariate framework to the bivariate one, actually d = 2 is the dimension of the response variable and k = 9 is the dimension of the predictor variable. This above actually is just a part of the algorithm. Hence I need the indices set to carry on. Obviously I won't scan all the indices but will use them later to parameterize some matrices.

Comment: i thinks the best way for this problem is use a `iterator` and if you want to get all the subsets from itertator use list comprehension !

Comment: I don't know for sure that the 4.3e22 quoted by @DavidEisenstat is exactly the right number, because I haven't run the calculations myself, but it seems reasonable in my experience. Presumably you are also aware that a 64-bit integer only has slightly over 19 decimal digits precision, so you'll need something bigger than that to even index this list of subsets. I would suggest that it's time to find a different approach to the problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: 4.3e22 unfortunately it's right. I will try iterator @Kasra and will let you know.thanks

Comment: Also, keep in mind that, assuming a 32-bit integer, and contiguous storage for a set (which is most likely not achievable with Python sets), you'll need 4 bytes * 11 members = 44 bytes per set, which means 1.9e24 bytes (1.7e15 GB) of memory to store the list of sets. That's ever so slightly larger than the 8GB of memory you have...

Comment: yes, and as far as i know the fastest way for get the elements from iterator is using list comprehension , rather than using `map` or ...

Comment: And, assuming you can process 1 billion of these sets per second, it will be 4.3e13 seconds or 1.36e6 years = 1363 millenia before your program finishes... You're rather likely to die of old age before then, I would think.